# SQL Server filestream: how to read csv into table

Tags: sql, sql-server, filestream, sqlfilestream

I copied a `.CSV` file `dataset_with_pred2.csv` into the filestream folder in SQL Server. Is it possible to read it into table?

Now, everything I can do is to retrieve the `.csv` file into string via:

```
select cast(file_stream as varchar(max)) 
from [dbo].[MODEL_FILETABLE] with (READCOMMITTEDLOCK) 
where name = 'dataset_with_pred2.csv'
```

It returns comma separated values.

Comment: look up BULK INSERT, BCP

Comment: "_I copied csv-file "dataset_with_pred2.csv" into filestream folder in SQL-server._" That's not how filestream folders work - the files in there are managed by SQL Server itself.

Comment: Mitch Wheat, AlwaysLearning, thank you very much. If I understood you correctly, I shoud use something like: BULK INSERT Sales.Orders
FROM '\\server\folder\dataset_with_pred2.csv'
WITH ( FORMAT='CSV') regardless if the folder has filestream type.

Comment: "I copied a .CSV file dataset_with_pred2.csv into the filestream folder" - you don't need to do that. The file can be anywhere on the filesystem